# What are dronekit-python dependencies?

Tags: dronekit-python

The dronekit Getting Started page suggests installing WinPython to use dronekit-Python on Windows because it includes the dependencies. I already have a working Python installation and I prefer not to risk messing it up with WinPython. What are the dependencies I need to install?

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, share your installation instructions :-)

Answer (score 3):

**As of DKPY 2.0 this is outdated. Also, I might move to making a MavProxy module depending on whether or not the unpaid devs decide to stay when 3DR stops funding Dronekit**

I've written a procedure to help with this problem which I've pasted. 3DR claims they're going to fix it, but in the mean time I hope this will help.

This setup is for Windows 64-bit systems only, although similar procedures will work with 32-bit.

1. Install MAVProxy and run it once before reaching step 5.
2. Install Notepad++.
3. Install Python v2.7.
4. Inside the Python folder, run WinPython Control Panel and select Advanced->Register Python.
5. Inside the same folder, run WinPython Command Prompt and input the following four commands:
   •   pip uninstall python-dateutil
   •   pip install droneapi
   •   pip install console
   •   echo module load droneapi.module.api >> %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\MAVProxy\mavinit.scr
6. Install WX Python. It should be the 64-bit Python 2.7 version.
7. Download and install OpenCV 2.4.11 to any folder
   •   Copy/paste the file cv2.pyd from OpenCV\build\python\2.7\x64\ to \python-2.7.6.amd64\Lib\site-packages.

**Steps 8 through 11 apply to SITL only**

8. Follow the [online documentation](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/simulation-2/sitl-simulator-software-in-the-loop/sitl-native-on-windows/) for setting up Cygwin for SITL in Windows
9. Go to C:\cygwin\home\**Your Username**\ardupilot\Tools\autotest\
10. Open sim_vehicle.sh in Notepad++
    •   Change line 429 from…

    ```
    cygstart -w "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/MAVProxy/mavproxy.exe" $options --cmd="$extra_cmd" $*
    ```

    to...

    ```
    cygstart -w "/cygdrive/c/Users/YOUR USERNAME HERE/Desktop/WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4/python-2.7.6.amd64/Dronekit/Scripts/mavproxy.py" $options --cmd="$extra_cmd" $*
    ```

    Note: This location changes depending on where you installed WinPython. For me, it was the desktop.
11. Start simulations as you would normally for SITL. To run Python scripts during the simulations, use the command 
    •   api start **Path to script**\**script_name**
12. To use the code to connect to an actual copter, open WinPython Command Prompt
    •   Navigate to the folder which contains the scripts you wish to test
    •   Type mavproxy.py --master=”com##”,57600
    •   Run your script by typing into the MAVProxy terminal
    o    api start **script_name**